# Soma de TimeSpan em C#?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, timespan

Na soma de duas variáveis do tipo [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) com a linguagem [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) pude observar que acontece como se fosse uma operação matemática de dois números simples, ***exemplo***:

```
TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:01:45", "c", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:02:45", "c", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeSpan t3 = t1 + t2;
```

sendo que o resultado final disso são **4** *minutos* e **30** *segundos* na variável `t3`.

Duas estruturas teoricamente não deveriam fazer operações de soma de forma transparente, gostaria de saber o seguinte:

- Como funciona essa operação de soma das duas estruturas [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)?
- Isso pode ser feito em outras classes, como forma de facilitar as operações matemáticas ou de conversões, existe ***exemplos*** para demonstrar?

Comment: Sabendo que você conhece o assunto, tem alguma específica que deseja saber? O que está aí está correto. Ou seja, o que quer dizer com "Como funciona essa operação"? Que outras classes por exemplo? Com algumas certamente, com outras não? Ou poderia, depende da definição do que está querendo fazer. Por exemplo não existe no `DateTime` um `Add(DateTime)` e não foi esquecimento. Então nesse momnto estou achando não clara ou ampla, mas sei que você pode melhorar.

Comment: Não tem nenhuma especifica, falei de um modo geral. Como funciona essa operação no sentido amplo recursos da arquitetura `.net` propriamente dito, não se restringir somente `TimeSpan`, mas, sim se posso fazer isso em outros classes e estruturas. @bigown. É uma resposta geral. Sim eu conheço o assunto e não tem pergunta sobre ele especificamente.

Comment: Entendi então, depois eu vejo se consigo responder e se precisa já que tem duas respostas que podem ser boas, lerei depois.

Comment: Talvez com exemplos de `cast` @bigown seria um diferencial!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Como funciona essa operação de soma das duas estruturas TimeSpan?

Isso funciona porque o C# permite a [sobrecarga de operadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators), definindo métodos estáticos, usando a palavra-chave `operador`.

Para sobrecarregar um operador é necessário criar na classe um método estático denominado com o símbolo do operador que está sendo sobrecarregado.
Para operadores unários o método declará um parâmetro, no caso de operadores binários dois parâmetros.
O(s) parâmetro(s) deve(m) ser do mesmo tipo da classe/estrutura que declara o operador.

No caso do TimeSpan o [método](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,354) é assim:

```
public static TimeSpan operator +(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2) 
{
    return t1.Add(t2);
}
```

Por curiosidade o método [add()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,153) é assim:

```
public TimeSpan Add(TimeSpan ts) {
    long result = _ticks + ts._ticks;
    // Overflow if signs of operands was identical and result's
    // sign was opposite.
    // >> 63 gives the sign bit (either 64 1's or 64 0's).
    if ((_ticks >> 63 == ts._ticks >> 63) && (_ticks >> 63 != result >> 63))
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_TimeSpanTooLong"));
    return new TimeSpan(result);
}
```

> Isso pode ser feito em outras classes, como forma de facilitar as operações matemáticas ou de conversões, existe exemplos para demonstrar?

Sim, isso pode ser aplicado a qualquer estrutura/classe, apenas necessita de fazer a sobrecarga dos operadores que quer disponibilizar.

Exemplo de sobrecarga do operador `+` em uma estrutura que representa um número complexo.

```
public struct Complex 
{
   public int real;
   public int imaginary;

   public Complex(int real, int imaginary) 
   {
      this.real = real;
      this.imaginary = imaginary;
   }

   public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
   {
      return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
   }
}
```

No que diz respeito a conversões, é possível declará-las de forma implícita ou explicita.

[Exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) de uso dum operador de conversão de tipo para permitir a conversão implícita(sem usar *cast*) desse tipo em outro.

```
class Digit
{
    public Digit(double d) { val = d; }
    public double val;

    // Conversão de Digit to double
    public static implicit operator double(Digit d)
    {
        return d.val;
    }
    //  Conversão de double para Digit
    public static implicit operator Digit(double d)
    {
        return new Digit(d);
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
Digit dig = new Digit(7);
//Conversão implícita de Digit para double
double num = dig;
//Conversão implícita de double para Digit
Digit dig2 = 12;
```

[Exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) de uso dum operador de conversão de tipo para permitir a conversão explícita(invocada usando *cast*) desse tipo em outro.

```
class Celsius
{
    public Celsius(float temp)
    {
        degrees = temp;
    }
    public static explicit operator Fahrenheit(Celsius c)
    {
        return new Fahrenheit((9.0f / 5.0f) * c.degrees + 32);
    }
    public float Degrees
    {
        get { return degrees; }
    }
    private float degrees;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
Fahrenheit fahr = new Fahrenheit(100.0f);
//Conversão explicita de Fahrenheit para Celsius
Celsius c = (Celsius)fahr;
```

Answer (score 8):

A soma entre as duas estruturas funciona porque a linguagem permite fazer [sobrecarga de operador](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx).

> Como funciona essa operação de soma das duas estruturas TimeSpan?

Isso é definido na criação da estrutura, da mesma forma que são definidos campos, o construtor, etc. É um método estático com um tipo de retorno qualquer que contém a palavra reservada `operator`.

Algo como:

```
public static TimeSpan operator +(TimeSpan c1, TimeSpan c2) 
{
    // fazer a operação 
    return timeSpan;
}
```

> Isso pode ser feito em outras classes, como forma de facilitar as operações matemáticas ou de conversões, existe exemplos para demonstrar?

Sim. Existem alguns, basicamente você pode fazer qualquer coisa. Um exemplo básico uma estrutura que represente vetores bidimensionais.

Defini um método para fazer a soma de dois vetores, sobrecarregando o operador **`+`** e uma conversão de `int` para `Vector` - esta conversão é chamada de [User-Defined Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa288476(v=vs.71).aspx).

```
struct Vector
{
    public int ComponenteX;
    public int ComponenteY;

    public Vector(int cX, int cY){
        ComponenteX = cX;
        ComponenteY = cY;
    }

    public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2) 
    {
        return new Vector(v1.ComponenteX + v2.ComponenteX, v1.ComponenteY + v2.ComponenteY);
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector(int componenteX)
    {
        return new Vector(componenteX, 0);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ComponenteX}, {ComponenteY}";
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pMlGWi)

Comment: Eu ia sugerir exatamente isso :)

Comment: Primeira coisa que me veio na cabeça foi vetor, não sei porquê XD